# How to create an Imperative Azure Queue Input Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues, c#-8.0

I have an Azure Function that looks like follows:

```cs
namespace TestAzureFunction
{
    [StorageAccount("TEST_STORAGE_ACCOUNT")]
    public static class SendEmailTestQueue
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(SendEmailTestQueue))]
        public async static Task Run(
            [QueueTrigger("send-email-test-queue-name")]SendEmailTestQueueModel model,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            // SEND EMAIL
            logger.LogInformation("Email Sent");
        }
    }
}
```

and the way i add messages to queue is as follows:

```cs
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("** connectionString **");
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

CloudQueue queueReference = queueClient.GetQueueReference("send-email-test-queue-name");
await queueReference.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

SendEmailTestQueueModel model = new SendEmailTestQueueModel
{
    Subject = "Email Subject",
    Body = "Email Body"
}
CloudQueueMessage queueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
await queueReference.AddMessageAsync(queueMessage);
```

Now all that works fine.

#### **How can I make the declaration of azure function above [imperative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#binding-at-runtime)?**

Below is my failed attempt:

```cs
namespace TestAzureFunction
{
    public static class SendEmailTestQueue
    {
        public async static Task Run(
            Binder binder,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            var attributes = new Attribute[]
            {
                new QueueTriggerAttribute("send-email-test-queue-name"),
                new StorageAccountAttribute("TEST_STORAGE_ACCOUNT")
            };

            SendEmailTestQueueModel model = await binder.BindAsync<SendEmailTestQueueModel>(attributes);

            // SEND EMAIL
            logger.LogInformation("Email Sent");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: no update yet, https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1429

Answer (score 0):

For now it's doesn't support imperative binding pattern with trigger. Please scroll down the bottom of the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#multiple-attribute-example) you provide.

It lists the attributes for each binding type, and about the storage queue, you could find it only provides the `QueueAttribute` and `StorageAccountAttribute`.

And from your code, suppose you want to use `QueueAttribute` binding to send queue message. The simplest way is use the `Queue` [output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#output).

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("%queuename%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log,
            [Queue("queuetest",Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]CloudQueue outqueue
            )
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
            CloudQueueMessage queueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(myQueueItem);
            outqueue.AddMessageAsync(queueMessage);

        }
```

As for the Imperative output binding, you could refer to the below code.

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([QueueTrigger("%queuename%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log,
            IBinder binder
            )
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
            var queuearribute = new QueueAttribute("test");
            var queue = await binder.BindAsync<CloudQueue>(queuearribute);
            await queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(myQueueItem));

        }
```